# Are there cases where perfect forwarding actually improves performance?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I'm not entirely sure whether I understand perfect forwarding correctly. I've tested the two functions:

```
template <typename T,typename Arg>
T createA(Arg&& a){
  return T(std::forward<Arg>(a));
}


template <typename T,typename Arg>
T createB(Arg a){
  return T(std::move(a));
}
```

and [compared the compiled code](https://godbolt.org/z/X6H_Gv). It does not seem to make any difference with optimizations. Is there actually a performance gain using perfect forwarding in practice, compared to a normal pass by value followed by a move? Am I using it the wrong way?

**Edit**: Changed the code to use template functions

Comment: if you have a R value reference &&, than you should move it, forward will do it but you just need move(a) in the first case

Comment: (1) is not really a perfect forwarding, it's just a constructor accepting an rvalue reference. For it to be perfect forwarding, the constructor has to be a template, and its template parameter must be used instead of `T`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Does that make a difference since the whole class is a template and T in this case is a template parameter as well?

Comment: For any type that manages a resource that can be moved, perfect forwarding always improves performance over copying.  For any type that manages a non-copyable resource, perfect forwarding is an improvement over not-being-able-to-compile.

Comment: @Julius: it makes difference, for `my_class<std::string>`, yo have `my_class(std::string&&)` constructor, it is not a forwarding reference, you only accept rvalue reference.

Comment: @Julius For an rvalue reference to count as a forwarding reference (i.e. be able to bind to both lvalues and rvalues), the type of the reference must be deduced at the point where you call the function. In your case the type is fixed as `std::vector<int>`, so you can only pass rvalues. (So the constructor must have its own template parameter. Or you could use [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), but in this case it doesn't make much sense, since you probably don't want `T myfield;` to become a reference.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That makes sense. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: In any case, in your example both (1) and (2) do the same amount of moves. Try something like `std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3}; myclass<std::vector<int>> ab(std::move(v));`, then (2) should lose by one move.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I tried that, seems to compile to the same though :-(

Answer (score 1):

You basically have those constructor options:

```
class myclass {
public:
    // #1 myclass(const std::string& s) : s(s) {}
    // #2 myclass(std::string&& s) : s(std::move(s)) {}

    // #3 myclass(std::string s) : s(std::move(s)) {}

    // #4 template <typename T> myclass(T&& t) : s(std::forward<T>(t)) {}

    std::string s;
};
```

`#3` cannot be present with `#1` or `#2` -> ambiguous call

and call

```
std::string s;
myclass A(s);
myclass B(std::move(s));
myclass C("temporary");
myclass D({5, '*'});
```

Following is count of copy/move constructor

```
                        | A | B | C | D |
------------------------|---|---|---|---|
1                  Copy | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
const l-value ref  Move | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
                  Other | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
------------------------|---|-v-|-v-|-v-|
2                  Copy | X | 0 | 0 | 0 |
r-value ref        Move | X | 1 | 1 | 1 |
                  Other | X | 0 | 1 | 1 |
------------------------|---|---|---|---|
3                  Copy | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
by value           Move | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
                  Other | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
------------------------|---|---|---|---|
4                  Copy | 1 | 0 | 0 | X |
Forwarding ref     Move | 0 | 1 | 0 | X |
                  Other | 0 | 0 | 1 | X |
----------------------------------------/
```

Possible configurations:

- `#1` only: handle all cases, but does copy for temporary
- `#1/#2`: (B/C/D would use `#2`), so best results except for in-place construct
- `#3` only: Handle all cases, but does extra move
- `#4` only: Handle most regular cases, best results
- `#1/#2/#4`: best results (Notice that `#4`) has exact match over non-const l-value)
- `#2/#4`: Best results

Purpose of `#3` is to write only one overload.

As you can see Forwarding reference (`#4`) has best result.

Comment: So the difference between 3 (by value) and 4 (Forwarding ref) are more move operations, right? Could it be that the compiled result is the same in the example because the compiler can optimize those out?

Comment: @Julius: With all code visible, compilers might indeed optimize and elide constructor, if you hide some implementation and forbid elision, we have indeed 1 less call to move constructor with forwarding version [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/neQdI_)